# How do I get the lat-long coordinate of point 1 from a survey plan

Tags: coordinate-system, land-survey, bearing, metes-and-bounds, legal-description

Here are the data from the survey plan:

```
TIE LINES from BLLM No. 3, PLS 561, to corner "1" of:

LOT ----------Bearing--------------------Distance  
Boundary ----S 36deg 41min W ------11,641.21 meters  

BOUNDARY: 

LINE ----- BEARING ------------- DISTANCE   
1-2 ------ N 37deg 58min E ----- 251.18 meters  
2-3 ------ S 50deg 42min E ----- 199.73 meters  
3-4 ------ S 38deg 28min W ----- 248.00 meters  
4-1 ------ N 51deg 37min W ----- 197.58 meters
```

Obviously the map has 4 points. If only I can get the lat-long reading of point 1 so that I can readily verify "on field" if it did not overlap to adjacent lots.
Additionally, if lat-long coordinates of point 1 is known, I can easily check on the other three points and determine its position thru Bearings describe in the title/map.

I only need the process on how to do this, but it there is an application or software to do this, much better.

Comment: The origin is stated as 'BLLM No. 3, PLS 561', you need to find PLS561 to get the origin coordinate then you're about 11k from that by bearing/distance. Surveyors love to tie their surveys into existing surveys or known permanent survey marks for neatness; the accuracy of the surveys and known marks can change (be more refined) over time the survey remains the same (but changes with it) as a relationship, if the origin was set as an absolute it wouldn't move with the mesh and would very quickly become 'wrong'

Comment: Thank you for your response, I just want to be clarified on this: does PLS-561 has the lat-long coordinate?

Comment: That's how I read it. Whether PLS-561 is a permanent survey mark or existing survey I can't tell.

Comment: It depends on the survey and monumentation process. Not all monuments have lat/long, and those that do are only based on a particular survey date/network. More information about the location/country would be needed to suggest anything further, but as Michael said, "BLLM No. 3, PLS 561" is a monument or survey control point from a network with known coordinates of some kind.

Comment: Thank you Chris, then I guess I should go and do more leg work then.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Outline a plot of land on a map](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120872/outline-a-plot-of-land-on-a-map)

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. 
You seem to have *two* or *three* questions here: (1) How do i get the coordinates of BLLM No. 3, PLS 561? (2) How do i compute lot coordinates from survey metes? (3) How do i convert survey grid coordinates to geographic lat-long?

Comment: You might use the [NGS survey mark app](http://www.ngs.noaa.gov/datasheets/) to find ones in the area. Maybe you'll be able to link up the name (I wonder if it's BLM rather than BLLM?).